# Get returned value from post method with observables

Tags: post, null, angular2-observables

I need returned value from post method. I tried to map data, but it (newTask) stays null. I don't know how to get Tasks object out of this function.  Any help, please.

```
    public PostTask(task:Tasks){

        let headers=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
        let options=new RequestOptions({headers:headers});


       this._http.post('http://localhost:58592/api/tasks',task,options)
            .map(res => res.json() as Tasks)
            .map(newTask=>this.newTask=newTask) 
            .catch(this.handleError).subscribe();


    }
```

Comment: Second map seems unnecessary. You can just do `.map(res => this.newTask = res.json())`. Other than that, are you sure your api works as expected? Do you see your json data on dev tools/network tab?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, yes. I see it  after GettAllTasks() method.

Comment: How and when do you try to access your `this.newTask`? Keep in mind that this is an async operation. If you try to access it right after you call this method, it will be null.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, just after PostTask actually((. Thanks for noticing it. I am really new. Is there any way to know when newTask will be initialized?

Comment: If you need to do something with it, do it within map or subscribe method. You can't know for sure when it will be available

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, okay. Thank you for response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.get()` returns an observable. To extract a value from an observable once it is emitted we should subscribe to it after transforming emitted values.

```
this._http.post('http://localhost:58592/api/tasks',task,options)
        .map(res => res.json() as Tasks)
        .subscribe( 
                newTask =>  this.newTask = newTask ,
                error => console.log(error);
        );
```

Please read through the [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http) documentation and examples.